# Gravity form ajax not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress with woocommerce and I want to list products based on the answers by customers. I am using gravity form for question and answers. One question should be appear at a time. When we go for next question by clicking next, the page is reloading, but I want it should be in ajax.

Here is the shortcode am using,

```
[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```

The ajax is not working. Any Help appreciated.

Comment: You should better contact "sparkle store" theme authors support threads. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: Sorry, my theme is not a problem. because Now I changed sparkle store into default wordpress theme and tested. Still ajax is not working. Having issue somewhere. Can you please help?

Comment: On this kind of questions you have very low chances to get helped here and even less as gravity forms is a commercial software. So you should better contact gravity form authors support threads. This community is coding related and don't handle any software support.